# How can I add a direct call and text button to my custom phone app in the contact's profile page of Android Phone Contacts app?

Tags: android, text, call, contacts, whatsapp

I want to be able to add a button to initiate a text or call to my custom app within the contact profile page of the Android phone contacts app. The Android phone contacts app is native, so it's a little bit tricky to find a way to do this and it seems there is not much information online. The call and text buttons will appear as list contact numbers within the contact profile page, and they will have clickable actions and will be redirected to my own app for handling.

A perfect example is WhatsApp (please see screenshots), they were able to put a direct call-to-action buttons within the contact profile page.

[image: Sample WhatsApp account linking]

So far, I have tried adding an Intent filter to my manifest to tell Android that I can handle calling and texting. Some of the ideas I also found are storing metadata to a specific device contact using the Contacts Provider API to link them, and then associating a custom mimetype as well. Then adding an intent filter in the manifest with this mimetype to tell Android that my app can handle it. However, both of these approaches still fail to show the call-to-action buttons within the contact profile page.

If you guys have any ideas on implementing this and maybe some links to put me in the right direction. I will highly appreciate it.

Comment: Here's a related link on how to implement this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35042912/how-do-i-make-the-native-address-book-display-an-option-to-call-via-my-applicati

Looks promising so far. It looks like the contact was synced with an account associated with my app, but it is still not showing as an option for call or text, just like Skype.

Do you have any ideas if I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0):

use these properties in your phone number textview for auto detect of phone numbers.

```
android:autoLink="phone"
android:linksClickable="true"
```

Comment: I would like to know more context about this. Will this add new options in the Android contacts phone app?