# Add a custom button in call history in Android

Tags: java, android, mobile

My requirement is in the title. I want add a button in the default call log app in `Android`. Clicking the button would open my app with the call content copied. Is this even possible to do? [How do I make the native address book display an option to call via MY_APPLICATION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35042912/how-do-i-make-the-native-address-book-display-an-option-to-call-via-my-applicati) this link discuss how to do this in contact app. I am asking if this is possible in call history app. Surfing the internet suggets that this is not possible, unless one changes the firmware.

Comment: If dodgy apps and bloatware could do this, your call log app would already look like [early 2000s browser toolbar nightmare](https://www.reddit.com/r/nostalgia/comments/xbehqk/2000s_internet_explorer_spyware_toolbars/).

Comment: @teapot418 I don't understand. I dont want to build a seperate call log app.

Comment: My point was that this ability would be too attractive to advertisers and such. If your call app does not have a million buttons, that is a sign that no one can do this. If you want to build a mutant call log app, you don't have to start from scratch, the default one is available including source code as part of AOSP.

Comment: @teapot418, it's just that this is a requirement that has come up. In fact in Ios, truecaller app has the capability to write small texts in call history app.